# Duplicating 2 columns in a database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, localdb

I am struggling to duplicate data from one column to the next. I want `foodId` and `MenuItemId` to be the same. Is there a way to add a code in the Controller to have both columns to have the same value? This is how it looks like currently:

```
FoodId   | MenuItemId | Rating
---------+------------+------
1        | NULL       |   5
1        | NULL       |   4
2        | NULL       |   5
1        | NULL       |   5
```

I would like my end result to look like this:

```
FoodId   | MenuItemId | Rating
---------+------------+------
  1      |     1      |   5
  1      |     1      |   4
  2      |     2      |   5
  1      |     1      |   5
```

This is my controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
{
    var listOfNumbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var listOfRatings = listOfNumbers.Select(x => new { Id = x, Value = x.ToString() });

    ViewData["Rating"] = new SelectList(listOfRatings, "Id", "Value");
    ViewData["FoodId"] = new SelectList(_context.MenuItems, "Id", "Name");

    return View();
}
    
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Title,FoodReview,Rating,Date,FoodId,MenuItemId,UserId")] Reviews reviews)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var userId = _userManager.GetUserId(HttpContext.User);

        reviews.UserId = userId;
        reviews.Date = DateTime.Now;

        _context.Add(reviews);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    var listOfNumbers = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var listOfRatings = listOfNumbers.Select(x => new { Id = x, Value = x.ToString() });

    ViewData["Rating"] = new SelectList(listOfRatings, "Id", "Value", reviews.Rating);
    ViewData["FoodId"] = new SelectList(_context.MenuItems, "Id", "Name", reviews.FoodId);

    return View(reviews);
}
```

Comment: Why do you need the same data in other column as well?

Comment: its a mistake thats too late to fix, however, having the same data in the other column will solve the problem.

Comment: Add line reviews.MenuItemId = reviews.FoodId

Comment: would this go under the Post Create method?

Comment: Yes below this line reviews.UserId……

Comment: Shouldn't you just fix this with a simple sql query on the server?

Comment: it will be easier to have the columns duplicated than to fix it on the server

Answer (score 0):

you can link these properties using getter setter

```
public class Review
{
public int Id {get; set;}

,,,,, another properties

public int MenuItemId
{
get {return FoodId}
set { FoodId=value}
}

public int FoodId {get; set;}

}
```

or on the contrary , what you like more